# How to deal with an exploitative supervisor toward the end of PhD?

Tags: phd, thesis, supervision

I hate my thesis and I hate my supervisor for he is one of the most manipulative and insensitive human beings I have ever met. He forced me to work on his ideas which I never liked. I could not quit my Ph.D. because I had some bigger problems of my own in personal front and cannot afford the pressure of being jobless. And there was a serious lack of alternative in my university so could not change supervisors, not that there was any support.

I have somehow completed my thesis.

Comment: Considering where you are now, getting your doctorate will be the best revenge you can hope for.

Comment: Does your University have a Research Office, Postgraduate office, or similar office dealing with PhD candidates? Do you have co-supervisors? Did you discuss your issue with them? Or perhaps with the Head of Department?

Comment: Is the choice of the title of your thesis really that important to you? It's just a title nobody really cares about. What matters is what is *in* the thesis, not the title that is *on* it.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov My supervisor very cleverly instituted PostDoc students as my co-supervisors who were later made lecturers.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Its not about the title. Its about being forced and being exploited.

Comment: @Damodar -- you took that statement out of your post, but now the post really has no question left. What do you hope for us to help you here?

Answer (score 6):

Based on your post history you've had some issues with this PI over a long time but you haven't moved to another lab. Either the problems were big enough and you should have moved or quit, or they were manageable.

At this point, you sound very close to finishing your degree, and you need to just finish. Of all the ways a PI could potentially be exploitative, giving you direction to work on a project to the point of having a completed thesis isn't really even on the map. It seems like you are describing a conflict of expectations, which doesn't necessarily have anything to do with exploitation, it's just a conflict of expectations and should have been addressed long ago, not now.

The specific issues you raise in your post: the title and acknowledgment of your thesis, are simply things that don't really matter much. You're describing some struggles with mental health: try to see a counselor/therapist of some sort, especially if your institution has support for those sorts of resources, and get your own head sorted out, but as far as your thesis just finish and let yourself move on to another situation that you will hopefully be happier in.

Answer (score 5):

I see two extreme possibilities. Unfortunately I don't have enough information to choose which is closer to the truth. Based on this and other questions you've asked here, you've been unhappy for quite a while.

**First Extreme**. You are completely accurate here and your advisor is a complete abusive jerk.

Your best option, I think, is to swallow your anger, take his advice, finish, and find a position in which you can be your own person. This is a strategic move suggestion. It doesn't have to be "right" in any other sense than that i gives you a way forward.

**Second Extreme** You are completely wrong and your advisor is giving you excellent advice that will ultimately advance your career. You are just being obstinate, refusing good advice.

Your best option, I think, is to swallow your pride, take his advice, finish and find a position in which you can prosper.

I don't know whether either extreme accurately describes the situation, with so little to go on and not knowing any of the personalities. But the fact that the solutions are essentially the same, suggests that if the real situation lies between the extremes then the same solution is probably the best one.

Getting out with your degree is your best option. Just do it. Keep your eye on the prize.

Comment: I am doing that. But the price I am paying for that is killing me. I need a proper and correct method to get back at him. I just do not know what that is.

Comment: @Damodar - there is no proper and correct way to get back at someone.

Comment: Trying to "get back at him" could well be an act of professional suicide. That is why I suggested swallowing your anger. In self defense martial arts your best outcome is to go home safely, not to "punish" your attacker, who may be able to turn it against you.

Answer (score 1):

Take your life into your own hands. **You're responsible.** Don't play sheep.

You have made a number of mistakes. Who hasn't? The quintessential one is unfortunately widespread and a big problem in academia: **working towards a degree is not a job**.

You must decide what you need and go for it. Do you need a degree? Go for it.
You have made the mistake of choosing a bad adviser. Now *you* deal with it. Realize he did not truly force you into doing anything.

**Defend whatever you did, deliver your papers and get out of this place.**

Next time you need a job: find a *real* job! Is a postdoctoral fellowship a real job? Think about it.

Good luck!